# Proxy issues DocumentDb and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create an sample application using NodeJs and Azure DocumentDb. I have added required DocumentDb SDK from npm.

I am getting an issue while trying to create document to my sample database endpoint and it seems like an **Proxy** issue. Please let me know how we can provide proxy configuration to DocumentDB SDK from nodejs.

[image]

CODE

```
var DocumentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;
var endpoint = "***********";
var authKey = "**********";

var client = new DocumentClient(endpoint, { "masterKey": authKey });
var databaseDefination = { "id": "AzureDocsData" };

var collectionDefination = { "id": "MyAzureDocs" };

var documementDefination = {
    id: "HelloWorld_042D_535D_xYg3H_140Op",
    stuff: "Hello World"
};


client.createDatabase(databaseDefination, function (err, database) {
    console.log("DATABASE CREATION ERROR : ", err);
    client.createCollection(database._self, collectionDefination, function (err, collection) {
        client.createDocument(collection._self, documementDefination, function (err, document) {
            client.queryDocuments(collection._self, "SELECT * FROM docs d WHERE d.stuff = 'Hello World'").toArray(function (err, result) {
                console.log("RESULT", result)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you share your code in here for analyzing the issue? I don't see the `Proxy` mean. There are two helpful code samples you can refer to, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/?service=documentdb&platform=nodejs.

Comment: It seems to be not any obvious issue in your code. Based on my understanding, the proxy issue you said means the issue was caused by the network environment, but I think the error info `connect ECONNREFUSED` means the server refused the connection. Is the `authKey` for the property `masterKey` correct? Please refer to the docs https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-secure-access-to-data/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783364.aspx which may be helpful for positioning the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proxy set up in your environment?  If not, one possible issue is that the endpoint might not have been entered correctly.  You can get the endpoint URI by logging into Azure Portal.  In the Azure Portal, navigate to your DocumentDB account and click on the "key" icon on the Account blade and you should see the URI there.

Comment: Yes we have proxy set up